# CORS issue in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

I am building a simple ionic/angular mobile app. I am using IntelliJ IDEA for development.

During development, I simply use 'ionic serve' command from Intellij terminal, to launch the mobile app in browser. The app connects to a REST service which is deployed on a Tomcat server.

When app tries to connect to REST service, it gives me the below error in browser console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/MyWorkflows/rest/UserService/users. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I understand that this is happening as REST services are running on a different domain and hence browser blocks it. However, I am at a loss to understand how should I proceed?

Can someone please help.

Comment: do you have control over tomcat app? can you make changes in the codebase?

Answer (score 1):

In your REST service deployed on Tomcat you should set *Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100* and you need to allow the http request methods you use with *Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS*.

This tells the browser that your service allows the web app running on http://localhost:8100 to access the service. The browser checks this on resource request. For http request methods other than GET there might be an additional Preflight Request added, so you need to have your WebService answering that as well.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

If you do not control remote end, use **Ionic CLI proxy server**. There is very good how-to article on Ionic blog: [Handling CORS issues in Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/).